# Unable to build Chromium for Android on Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit

Tags: android, chromium, ubuntu-13.10

I have Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit OS and i just try to build android content shell by this Step from [Code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/AndroidBuildInstructions)

Following Steps and command are running fine in my Ubuntu system.

```
gclient sync --nohooks
. build/android/envsetup.sh
gclient runhooks
```

I have also update my android build script as per issue patch from this https://codereview.chromium.org/222183002/#ps20001 so as per that two patch i update my `install-build-deps-android.sh` which located as `src/build/install-build-deps-android.sh`

According to this SO answer -->[failures-during-chromium-build-on-ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595947/failures-during-chromium-build-on-ubuntu)

i have set all this as well :

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/javac 50000
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java 50000
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/javaws 50000
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javap javap /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/javap 50000
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/jar jar /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/jar 50000
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/jarsigner jarsigner /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/jarsigner 50000

 ninja -C out/Release content_shell_apk
ninja: Entering directory `out/Release'
ninja: warning: multiple rules generate icudtl.dat. builds involving this target will not be correct; continuing anyway
[16/10277] ACTION Generating JNI bindings f...roid-19/android.jar/java/util/HashSet.class
FAILED: cd ../../content; ../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py -j /home/ubbvand2/himanshu/FreshCheckout/src/third_party/android_tools/sdk//platforms/android-19/android.jar --input_file java/util/HashSet.class --output_dir ../out/Release/gen/content/jni --includes base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator_helper.h --optimize_generation 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 1346, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 1342, in main
    GenerateJNIHeader(input_file, output_file, options)
  File "../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 1230, in GenerateJNIHeader
    jni_from_javap = JNIFromJavaP.CreateFromClass(input_file, options)
  File "../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 576, in CreateFromClass
    jni_from_javap = JNIFromJavaP(stdout.split('\n'), options)
  File "../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 524, in __init__
    signature=JniParams.ParseJavaPSignature(contents[lineno + 1]))]
  File "../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 172, in ParseJavaPSignature
    return '"%s"' % signature_line[signature_line.index(prefix) + len(prefix):]
ValueError: substring not found
[16/10277] ACTION Generating JNI bindings f.../android.jar/android/view/MotionEvent.class
FAILED: cd ../../content; ../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py -j /home/ubbvand2/himanshu/FreshCheckout/src/third_party/android_tools/sdk//platforms/android-19/android.jar --input_file android/view/MotionEvent.class --output_dir ../out/Release/gen/content/jni --includes base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator_helper.h --optimize_generation 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 1346, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 1342, in main
    GenerateJNIHeader(input_file, output_file, options)
  File "../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 1230, in GenerateJNIHeader
    jni_from_javap = JNIFromJavaP.CreateFromClass(input_file, options)
  File "../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 576, in CreateFromClass
    jni_from_javap = JNIFromJavaP(stdout.split('\n'), options)
  File "../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 524, in __init__
    signature=JniParams.ParseJavaPSignature(contents[lineno + 1]))]
  File "../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py", line 172, in ParseJavaPSignature
    return '"%s"' % signature_line[signature_line.index(prefix) + len(prefix):]
ValueError: substring not found
[16/10277] CC obj/third_party/icu/source/common/icuuc.ucnvmbcs.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Can any one known how to come out from this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using JDK 1.8,  you have to use JDK 1.6 to build.
See: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/AndroidBuildInstructions#Oracle_Java_JDK

Comment: i think you are right now my build is going on rather then stop at Error like in my question ,Hope it will complete without any issue further.

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem, and the reason is use the make version 4.x, when change to make v3.81, it's ok.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Please see [When should I comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)